# DateTime format wrong

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In here I take `StartDate` & `EndDate` as date time & `StartTime`, `EndTime` as time. I need to Alter time portion from `StartDate` and `EndDate`. Then add `StartTime` & `EndTime` to it. Here is my try. But at the last part it shows me error.

> > Error is : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

```
            string StartTime = "";
            string EndTime = "";

            DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(RadDatePickerStart.SelectedDate); 
            DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(RadDatePickerEnd.SelectedDate);

            if (RadTimePickerStart.SelectedDate != null)
                StartTime = RadTimePickerStart.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("HH:mm");

            if (RadTimePickerEnd.SelectedDate != null)
                EndTime = RadTimePickerEnd.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("HH:mm");

            DateTime NewStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate + " " + StartTime);<-- In here shows the error
            DateTime NewEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate + " " + EndTime);
```

Actually I need to add Date to the time, In here I need to alter time portion from `StartDate` & add start time to it.

Comment: Well have you verified exactly *what* value is the result of `StartDate + " " + StartTime` ?

Comment: What is the value of `SelectedDate`?

Comment: It's entirely unclear why you need string operations here at all. It would really help if you'd clarify your question.

Comment: I would use the `DateTime.TimeOfDay` property instead of `string` that will result into a `TimeSpan` object.

Comment: As a test, I ran a console app with the following `var result = Convert.ToDateTime("12/03/2010" + " " + "12:34");` and it wokred fine. So we need to know exactly what `StartDate` and `StartTime` contains

Comment: @JonSkeet No.I just want to Alter DateTime pickers Time portion & add Time pickers time to it.

Comment: @JasonEvans SelectedDate value comes like normal DateTime picker Value

Comment: @Johan: What do you mean "No"? No what? Your question is unclear, and is still unclear. You should edit it to make it clearer, so more people will be able to help you. It looks like you've only got two inputs - `RadTimePickerStart` and `RadTimePickerEnd` - but you're trying to use them as if there were four (two dates, and two times).

Comment: I guess when you concatenate there is already a `Time` portion and you are then appending an additional time part which i presume will not be parsed

Answer (score 2):

In C# the + operator is overloaded for most system types, just add them together. So you should also just take the Date object from the picker, instead of converting it to a string.

Edit: Now the final DateTime will be the result of adding the Date from the   RadDatePickers  and the Time from the  RadTimePickers.

```
            DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(RadDatePickerStart.SelectedDate);
            DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(RadDatePickerEnd.SelectedDate);

            TimeSpan StartTime, EndTime;

            if (RadTimePickerStart.SelectedDate != null)
                StartTime = RadTimePickerStart.SelectedDate.Value.TimeOfDay;

            if (RadTimePickerEnd.SelectedDate != null)
                EndTime = RadTimePickerEnd.SelectedDate.Value.TimeOfDay;

            RadDatePickerStart.SelectedDate = StartDate + StartTime;
            RadDatePickerEnd.SelectedDate = EndDate + EndTime;
```

Edit: I don't know how to set the DateTime of your pickers, you may need to adjust that part of the code.

Comment: No.I just want to Alter DateTime pickers Time portion & add Time pickers time to it.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use the `Convert.ToDateTime` instead of use `DateTime.TryParseExact` and make the `string` as concatinating the date and time later convert to date.

This sample code snippet will helps you,

```
DateTime dateasof;
bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact("08/06/2013 13:50", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateasof);
if (result)
    return dateasof;
```

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
DateTime StartDate = RadDatePickerStart.SelectedDate.Value; 
DateTime EndDate = RadDatePickerEnd.SelectedDate.Value;

if (RadTimePickerStart.SelectedDate != null)
            StartDate = StartDate.Date.Add(RadTimePickerStart.SelectedDate.Value.TimeOfDay);
if (RadTimePickerEnd.SelectedDate != null)
            EndDate =  EndDate.Date.Add(RadTimePickerEnd.SelectedDate.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess the main problem arises in the place where you concatenate

```
DateTime NewStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate + " " + StartTime);<-- In here shows the error
```

Here the `StartDate` will already have a time component defaulted to midnight and you are appending a further time component to this, so this won't be parsed

it would become something like `08/06/2013 12:00:00 AM 05:00:00`

you need to provide more details as what exactly is your purpose

you can use `DateTime Result = StartDate + StartTime;// StartTime as timespan`

(if you are parsing `StartTime` as `DateTime` then use the `TimeOfDay` property to get the `TimeSpan`)
or

`DateTime Result = StartDate.Add(StartTime);`